# UICollectionViewCell get repeat after 4th cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I made custom calendar by use of nested `UICollectionView`. It works properly. but the problem is after 4th cell of `CollectionView` data get randomly repeated. I can't understand what is happening behind the scenes.

and after reload collection view all data filled randomly.

[image]

Can anybody provide any suggestion or any kind of explanations.

thanks for your time !!!

Comment: Can you show any code?

Comment: It is likely a cell reuse bug, but we can't tell unless you post your code.